# Does it make sense

Tags: meaning

I hope, london to have protected her citizen in bad times
Does it make same sense exactly
I hope that london will protect her citizens in bad times

Comment: Is london the name of a person or are you referring to the city?

Comment: City name in those sentence

Comment: That sentence is full of mistakes. And please punctuate properly. You should check parts of your sentence. For example: "in bad time", before posting here.

Answer (score 1):

> I hope that London will protect its citizens in bad times.

I think this is what you are trying to say

Comment: Yes.are those two sentence express same meaning

Comment: I would note that @Kevin has corrected citizens to make it plural.  Also,  it is not common in English any longer to apply a gender to a city, but it is not unheard of.  Because it's uncommon, if you are to apply 'Her' to London instead of 'Its', it should be purposeful and for good reason.  If you are consciously portraying London as a protective mother, then in that context, 'Her' would be acceptable.